# How to hide duplicates in django template - table?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have dict:

```
my_dict = {
    '1': [],
    '2': [],
    '3': ['some_text'],
    '4': ['some_text'],
    '5': ['some_text'],
    '6': [],
    '7': ['other_text'],
    '8': []
}
```

And I want to display this in template:

```
+--------+------------------------------+
|   1    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   2    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   3    | some_text                    |
+--------+                              +
|   4    |                              |
+--------+                              +
|   5    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   6    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   7    | other_text                   |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   8    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

For now I have:

```
{% for skey, svalue in sdict.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ skey }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% for val in svalue %}
                {{ val }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and output:

```
+--------+------------------------------+
|   1    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   2    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   3    | some_text                    |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   4    | some_text                    |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   5    | some_text                    |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   6    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   7    | other_text                   |
+--------+------------------------------+
|   8    |                              |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

How to do it?

Comment: "['some_text']" list will always be a single value or there could be multiple values in it too?

Comment: single, but must be in list... but I try remove list

Comment: can you send more information from django view itself?

Comment: You could use the [`ifchanged` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) to avoid repeating the content, but that won't allow you to set a rowspan value on the td element.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how would this work if values keep on changing but they have duplicates in it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`{% regroup %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag with a converted version of your dictionary in conjunction with the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag.

First, you'd need to convert your dictionary in your view to something that works with the `{% regroup %}` tag, for instance a list of dictionaries:

```
sdict_converted = [{"column_one": k, "column_two": v} for k, v in sdict.items()]
```

This can then be used in your template like so:

```
{% regroup sdict_converted|dictsort:"column_one" by "column_two" as grouped_sdict_converted %}

{% for group in grouped_sdict_converted %}
    {% for item in group.list %}
    <tr>
        <td>
        {{ item.column_one }}
        </td>
        {% ifchanged item.column_two %}
        <td rowspan="{{ group.list|length }}">
            {% for nested_value in item.column_two %}
                {{ value }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>                    
        {% endifchanged %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```